# sprite's setPosition method does not work

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

So i have been trying to move the sprite wherever my body moves in the world. So i was using the sprite's setPosition method but turns out it didn't help. My Image just sits at the position (0,0) and i cant understand why.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.shapetest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;

class ShapeTest implements ApplicationListener {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    World world;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    Texture squareTx;
    Sprite square;
    Body body;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        world = new World(new Vector2(0,-10),false);
        squareTx = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sq.png"));
        square = new Sprite(squareTx);

        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);

        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
        bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bd.position.set(new Vector2((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) * 0.01f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.01f));
        body = world.createBody(bd);
        BodyDef bd2 = new BodyDef();
        bd2.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bd2.position.set(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 * 0.01f, 100 * 0.01f));
        Body body2 = world.createBody(bd2);

        square.setSize(100,100);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(0.5f,0.5f);
        PolygonShape shape2 = new PolygonShape();
        shape2.setAsBox(1.6f,0.3f);

        FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.density = 1;
        fd.restitution = 0.2f;
        fd.shape = shape;
        fd.friction = 0.4f;

        body.createFixture(fd);
        body2.createFixture(shape2, 0f);

        shape.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Vector2 pos = body.getPosition();
        square.setPosition(pos.x ,pos.y);

        camera.update();
                batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        Matrix4 cameraCopy = camera.combined.cpy();
        debugRenderer.render(world, cameraCopy.scl(100f));
        world.step(1/60f,10,10);
        batch.begin();
        square.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

(sprite should follow the pink box position)
[image: sprite should follow the pink box position]

Comment: You forgot `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`. And your camera needs to be resized in `resize()`. And it is convoluted to use a different camera scale for the box2d world and you game scene. Read up on LibGDX Viewports.

Comment: @Tenfour04 edited the code , added `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`, still the same result, not able to move the sprite to that pink box position

Comment: ...You're still not resizing camera or using viewports, or using same camera for the world and the game...

Comment: if you are referring to the yellow box. It looks to me could very well be at (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) * 0.01f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.01f), which coincidentally is the position you gave the body.

Comment: check this, may be it'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/43410465/3445320

Answer (score 0):

`body.getPosition()` return small value so for drawing you need to convert that value into pixel value.

According to you, sprite size is 100 pixels, and it represent dynamic physics body that is polygonShape having size `0.5f * 2 = 1;` unit in physics i.e you assuming 1 unit/meter of physics is equal to 100 pixels.

```
Vector2 pos = body.getPosition();   // value return in physics unit
square.setPosition(pos.x*100 ,pos.y*100);
```